# Technical introduction to ethereum

Tags: tutorials

Where can I find a technical explanation of how ethereum works for someone who knows a lot about crypto and bitcoin? Lecture or text would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the main Ethereum [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki), under the Basics section you'll find:

- the original [White Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper);
- the [Design Rationale](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale); and, for those more technically inclined...
- the [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/Paper.pdf).